# .bashrc analog for windows 10

Tags: windows, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros for windows and for using turtlebot3 I need to set environment the variable

```
set TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
```

every time
in ubuntu, we use to add

```
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
```

in .bashrc file so we don't need to perform it every time
how can I perform this in windows

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392256/.bashrc-analog-for-windows-10/) by [ohm](https://answers.ros.org/users/91042/ohm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-06**:
Add the command in the .bat file that starts the terminal script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the ROS on Windows installation in step 6:
http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=amd64 -host_arch=amd64&& set ChocolateyInstall=c:\opt\chocolatey&& c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\setup.bat
```

It's calling for 2 `.bat` files, you can add your `.bat` file to this startup script by adding `&&` then the name the path of your `.bat` file.

To learn how to create `.bat` file, check this tutorial:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/

Then you can add `set TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle` so you don't have to do it in every terminal.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2